# Exercise : find clique number and independence number of the given graph

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification

I have the following exercise to which there is no solution given so I wanted to know if my answers are correct :

$ω(G)$ is the size of a largest clique in the graph $G$ and $α(G)$ is the size of a largest set of independent vertices in $G$.

$G$ is the graph in which every vertex is equal to a set $S \subseteq \{ 1,2,3,4,5 \} $ of size 2. Two vertices are connected by an edge if and only if the two vertices have one exactly one element in common.
What are the values of $ω(G)$ and $α(G)$ ?

First, I assumed that a vertex cannot be of the format $ \{ x,x \} $ with $x \in \{ 1,2,3,4,5 \} $, which means there are ten vertices.

Next, we quickly notice that every vertex is connected to 6 other vertices (3 that have the first digit in common, 3 others that have the second digit in common, for example $v_{12}$ is adjacent to $v_{13}$, $v_{14}$, $v_{15}$, $v_{23}$, $v_{24}$, $v_{25}$). After quickly sketching what the graph could look like I realised that the largest cliques of the graph are of size 4, for example the clique $ \{ v_{12},v_{13},v_{14},v_{15} \} $. For the independant set, I realised that any pair of independent vertices will use 4 of the 5 available elements thus there is no way to add one more vertex to such an independent set. So I have :
$$ω(G)=4, α(G) = 2$$

Is this correct ? Is my assumption that a vertex cannot contain twice the same digit correct with the given formulation of the exercise ? There is something about the formulation that worries me but I can't say what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption about the subsets containing distinct elements is right, I'm sure. $\{2,2\}$ is exactly the same as $\{2\}$. Almost always.

Your main answer is also right but it's quite easy when you only have to deal with $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, it might be worth trying to extend it to general sets if you want to really understand the reasons why your answers ($4$ and $2$) are what they are.